# Why this Help Desk System redirects me to the old server?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I am using the [Liberum Help Desk](http://www.liberum.org/) as a Service Request System. It is host on a server that is running Windows Server 2008 R2 32-bit. I configured it with an Access database. It works well. Now, I am trying to shift it to another server running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. At the beginning, I have an error with the JET driver, because there is no JET driver for the 64-bit machines. I fixed it by enabling 32-bit option in the advanced settings of the application pool. However, I am still facing a strange problem which is the following:
When I tried to browse the system that is on the new server (64-bit), it will redirect me to the system hosted on the old server (32-bit) and I don't know why. I checked the code to see if there is any link or something for redirecting me to the old server and I did find anything.

**So how to fix this problem? what is the reason of it?**

Comment: Most probably the DNS record (or your DNS cache) is still pointing to the old system but there's really no way to tell for us without knowing more details.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution. The problem was with the Access Database; there is a table called config and inside it there is a column for determining the link. I changed the link there and everything works fine.